# cleveref is using "table" instead of "tabela" when the document is set to Portuguese

Tags: babel, cleveref

I'm using `cleveref` in a document in Portuguese. The caption of the figure gets a label in Portuguese, but when referencing it on the text it goes wrong. I switched to German and it worked as expected. It seems the problem is specifically in Portuguese package, whether using the option `brazil` or `portuguese`.

```
\documentclass[brazil,10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
Blablabla blabla \cref{tbl1}.
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Nananana} \label{tbl1}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why `cleveref` does not get the alias `brazil`, but it does work as expected with `brazilian`.

```
\documentclass[brazilian,10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\begin{document}
Blablabla blabla \cref{tbl1}.
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Nananana} \label{tbl1}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
1 & 2 \\
3 & 4
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]